# How to use generateProviderServiceMetadata() working with passport-saml

Tags: node.js, certificate, metadata, saml

I have the following issue:

I want to generate the SAML-metadata, for my SSO-ServiceProvider, using node.js and the package

['passport-saml'.](https://github.com/bergie/passport-saml)

This package includes the method 'generateServiceProviderMetadata( decryptionCert )' which will generate a service provider metadata document suitable for supplying to an identity provider.

this requires an decryptionCert...

Which decryptionCert shall I use, i.e. where and how to get it?

As far as I understand, I need something like:

```
  privateCert: fs.readFileSync('./cert.pem', 'utf-8')
```

where do I get './cert.pem' ?

Any advises and hints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In fact, you need to generate your own certificate for this. If you have private key, you can use it to generate cert file:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -key mykey.key -out certificate.crt
```

Where *mykey.key* is your existing key, and *certificate.crt* is newly generated certificate you should pass as a parameter to *generateServiceProviderMetadata* function.

If you don't have a private key yet, using this command will generate one for you:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout mykey.key -out certificate.crt
```

Of course, first you need to load cert. into memory using *fs.readFileSync*

So, here are steps:

 1. Generate .crt file

 2. Load it into variable: *var decryptionCert: fs.readFileSync('./certificate.crt', 'utf-8')*

 3. Generate metadata file, calling provided function:
*myStrategy.generateServiceProviderMetadata(decryptionCert)*

Comment: so for the 'passport-saml' example above, how would we call generateServiceProviderMetadata from app.js? I have steps 1 and 2 in place, but am not sure what to replace 'myStrategy' with your example with. I have tried `saml` as this what the strategy is defined as in config.js, I've also used 'SamlStrategy' and various other options that seemed likely.

Comment: It's the strategy object you get when you instantiate new SamlStrategy.


First, you create a new object: 
`var myStrategy= new saml.Strategy({
// config parameters
});`


Then, you can pass it to passport, but can use it later as well, for creating metadata:
`passport.use(myStrategy);`
`myStrategy.generateServiceProviderMetadata(decryptionCert);`

Comment: where does it generate this document? If I create the strategy, then call this method, passing in the same cert I use for the privateCert value, I get nothing in either stdio or generated file. I've also tried using the cert arg

Comment: @wkhatch In case it helps, I just answered that question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50682941/399105

Comment: thanks, @bmaupin. I got it printing to the console eventually, but it seems the configuration was pretty light and not really usable. I ended up using samltool.com to generate one for our idp